# How to translate an XML document in C struct using XSL

Tags: c, xml, xslt, struct

I have XML text formatted somewhat like this:

```
<root>
  <struct1>
     <el1 type="INT32" descript="Element No.1">0</el1>
     <el2 type="FLOAT32" descript="element No. 2</el2>
  </struct1>

  <struct2>
     <el3 type="INT32" descript="Element No.3">0</el3>
     <el4 type="STRING32" descript="element No. 4</el4>
  </struct2>

  <struct3>
     <el5 type="INT32" descript="Element No.5">0</el5>
     <el6 type="FLOAT32" descript="element No. 6</el6>
  </struct3>
</root>
```

and I want to translate this using XSLT into C code looking like this:

```
/*************************
* legal blah blah
************************************************************************/

#ifndef ROOT_H
#define ROOT_H

typedef struct
{
   INT32 el1;
   FLOAT32 el2;
} root_struct1_t

typedef struct
{
   INT32 el3;
   STRING32 el4;
} root_struct2_t

typedef struct
{
   INT32 el5;
   FLOAT32 el6;
} root_struct3_t

#endif
```

The requirement is that the header file will use the same name as the root element but in all caps and a '_H' appended (in my example, "root" so the header guard would be ROOT_H. The legal blah blah comment is always put at the head of the file.
The "level 1" elements (children of the root) must get translated as "typedef struct {...} X_Y_t where X is the root element name, Y is the element name, and the '_t" a constant text.
The children of these sub-elements get translated using the element name, and the type is given by the "type" attribute value.

Is there an XSL example of how to do something like this?

All the examples I found have the name of the element to be translated being the same for all elements (as in `<prop name="blahblah" type="moreblah" />`. That does not work for me.

The output side of this question is not so much the object of my question as "how do I extract the name of an element and some of the attributes and reuse them in the output?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
#ifndef <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(local-name(), $smallcase, $uppercase), '_H')" />
#define <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(local-name(), $smallcase, $uppercase), '_H')" />

    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
    typedef struct {
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="@type" /> <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />;
        </xsl:for-each>
    } <xsl:value-of select="concat(../local-name(), '_', local-name(), '_t')" />    
    <xsl:text>        
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

#endif
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

[XSLTranform](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwJ)

Basic idea here is to match any root node in the template, and then iterate using the `child::` axis.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I get, however, an error when I plug in your code: concat(../local-name -->(<-- .), '_', local-name(.), '_t').
It appears to happen when processing an XML comment but I see it even when I remove all comments from the XML.

Comment: hmm..  updated question, but if that doesn't work I'm not sure why (I removed the `.` in `local-name` calls, don't think it's necessary with a way i ended up refactoring the XSLT at some point).  The XSLT posted does work on your original posted XML (after fixing some missing quotes in attributes).

Comment: Lesson #1 in XSLT is actually "make sure your XML is well-formed". @SamDahan: please, do never *ever* state you got "an error". Quote the error message! FYI only, both old and new version work without a glitch with my basic Saxon 9.1 installation.

Comment: I did quote the error message - not very clearly though. And you're right, there is mal-formed XML in my example. But not in the full-scale file, with comments and all.
Anyway, your answer was on target, thank you very much!